# How to use Firebase Auth UI login buttons as id for onClickListener

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase AuthUi for Google login in my app and i want to display user info like name, email, profile pic in my Navigation bar. 
How can i set, when someone click on google login in firebase auth ui then his/her details can be used to display items in Nav bar. I know how to implement this but i need to set onClickListener on firebase Ui google login button and here comes the problem. Because for normal button we use findViewById(R.id.button_name).setOnClickListener but here i dont know the id of firebase auth ui buttons?. I am new to this so maybe you find my question silly.
Guide me please.

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns information about the current user (display name, etc). So once the user is logged in, you can initialize your ui. Is that what you need or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Actually when someone click google login button at login screen i want to call specific function after that. But i cannot do since i dont know the id of firebase Auth ui buttons.

Comment: You can probably find a hack to do that. But can you clarify again why? In your question, you said you needed to display user info which would happen _after_ the user logs in so no onClickListener is needed. What else are you trying to use the listener for?

Comment: Ayush your question is not clear. When you click on the google sign in button, you don't have user's information like name, pic ..etc. First you have to sign in the user and then you can access the user information. Checkout this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin. Find updateUI() function - I believe you should write your code there for user information display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i display information of person like name, email , profile pic in my navigation bar when he/she sign in via google account.?

In your `onActivityResult()` method, please add the following code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_REQUEST_CODE) {
       handleSignInResult(Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(result));
    }
}
```

And the `handleSignInResult()` method should look like this:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
    if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            //Get the data you need from the googleSignInAccount object
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more on informations [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount).